# when do luabind free created objects?

Tags: c++, lua, luabind

I'm having problems with luabind. I define a std::map to allocate objects created in lua. I publish this map as a global object in lua in this way:

```
luabind::globals(L)["g_SceneManager2D"] = this;
```

After that, this object is used into a function into lua, where many objects are created and inserted into this map. The problem comes when lua function ends and luabind returns the control to C++ side program, because automatically all contents of the map are lost.

I was looking for the error. I keep the lua context alive, so this object must exists.

Could you helpme??

Many thanks :)

Comment: If you post more code you'll probably get better answers: what type is `this` and the function declarations of the exported methods, also the Lua code that invokes those functions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest use a `shared_ptr<>(this)` rather than raw `this`.  `boost::shared_from_this` might help.  Make sure your class is registered using Luabind too, and that the `class_` is specified as held by a `shared_ptr`.

Another fun idea might be to make your Lua function just generate the "map" as a Lua table, return it, and you can iterate over it in C++ to build your `std::map`.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your problem correctly, it seems you are creating objects in Lua, which you then insert into the map (either through Lua or C++) and subsequently lose.  Without some more code, it's hard to tell exactly what the problem is.  However, I would first look to make sure that those objects are indeed being created (double check it) and then I would check to see that Lua isn't garbage collecting them.  If Lua is indeed garbage collecting those objects, then you won't see them on the C++ side because they're, well, gone.

If it helps, I'm finishing up a project which does something similar.  I had to create and retrieve C++ objects from Lua, but instead of creating the objects in Lua, I just called C++ functions to do it for me, sending any necessary data in the Lua call (bound by Luabind).  Those (C++) functions indexed the objects by IDs into hash tables and the IDs were returned to Lua in case it needed to retrieve the object script-side for operations.  This setup makes it easier (and safer) to handle memory stuff correctly and prevents Lua from garbage collecting your objects.